# Dynamic CSS width

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, I have this div container that spans across the page (please see the picture).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">Content length changes</div>
  <div class="B">Width dependent on "A"</div>
  <div class="C">fixed 27px width</div>
  <div class="D">fixed 27px width</div>
</div>
```

[image]

The issue is that the width of "A" is dynamic and it changes which means "B" width also changes (Although "B" will have minimum width of 27px).

I can measure the width of the "A" and change the css using jQuery but I want to know if there is a way to handle the width variables for "A" and "B" simply using CSS.

Comment: you mean `min-width`?  change it to 'width'. Please provide fiddle

Comment: sounds good. I will make one. thanks!

Comment: You can probably solve this pretty cleanly using Flexbox CSS properties like `flex-grow` or `flex-shrink`.

Comment: mm i see. I will look into that! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution without any flex. Simple CSS only.

```css
.A {
  float:left;
}
.B {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.C, .D {
  float: right;
  width: 27px;
  min-width: 27px;
}

/* beautiful appearance */
.container {
  border: 4px solid #999;
  padding: 8px;
}
.A, .B, .C, .D {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
.A { background: #ff6; }
.B { background: #69f; }
.C { background: #f60; }
.D { background: #6c6; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="D">D</div>
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="A">A. Content length changes</div>
  <div class="B">B. Dependent on "A"</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/Lf5fw9e6/

UPD. I've added a border to the container for clarity.

Comment: This is pretty clever! Thanks! =D

Comment: @HEYHEY I am glad to be helpful. I've added a border to the container for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did using flexbox

```css
div {
  border: 3px solid;
}
.child {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.container {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
}
.child.one {
  -webkit-flex: 5 1 200px;
  flex: 5 1 200px;
  color: green;
}
.child.two {
  -webkit-flex: 1 3 200px;
  flex: 1 3 200px;
  color: purple;
}
.child.three,
.child.four {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child one">
    Child One
    <br>Lorem ipsum
    <br>dolor sit amet
    <br>This is a bit longer line
  </div>

  <div class="child two">
    Two
  </div>

  <div class="child three">
    Three
  </div>

  <div class="child four">
    Four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you including `-webkit-` prefixes on `flex`? Chrome hasn't used prefixes for flex in over *twenty* major versions.